# How can I access a variable from JS in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

i have a Button in a `.cshtml`:

```
<div class="buttons-collection" style="text-align: center">
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Lengthy" asp-controller="Task" id="test" class="mb-1 mt-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i> alle Depotstände aktualisieren ASP</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need a script which put a `"asp-route-id="VARIABLE"` to this button where VARIABLE is from the `javascript` (`SignalR` connection Hub ID).

All what i tried goes wrong - did everyone has an idea ?

As i understand the `asp-action and asp-controller` is in `html` after rendering:

```
href="Task/Lengthy"
```

at the end i need

```
href="Task/Lengthy/VARIABLE"
```

Because i need the rerendering of the view it is necessary to use the asp-action thing,...the second button i use works well, but the view will not refresh:

```
<button class="mb-1 mt-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled"
                id="startButton"
                onclick="startTask()">
            <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i> alle Depotstände aktualisieren JS
        </button>
```

and the function:

```
<script>
    function startTask() {
        $.post("/Task/Lengthy/" + progressConnectionId);
    }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with asp-route-id because it is server side rendering. You need to do client side rendering like dynamically add html tag based on your criteria.

I think it is not going to work with Asp.net Mvc Core  Tag Helpers. I am giving solution by Old ways may be you already knows.

1.Modify button

```html
<a  id="test" class="mb-1 mt-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
    alle Depotstände aktualisieren ASP
</a>
```

2. script update by

```js
$("test").attr("href",” Task/Lengthy/”+ VARIABLE ))
```

Comment: @ jalil - thanx a lot for your response, you are right, after serverside Rendering the button have only a href="/link" instead the aps-action and so on...

Do you have an example how to change this button from javascript ? Because everytyhing i tried goes wrong....